# MQTT: does sport/# match sport/ (with a trailing slash)?

Tags: mqtt

The MQTT spec explicitly states that

> “sport/+” does not match “sport” but it does match “sport/”.

> “sport/#” also matches the singular “sport”, since # includes the parent level.

But does “sport/#” also match “sport/”?  The spec leaves this totally ambiguous.

As an aside, who else thinks allowing trailing slashes was a really bad design decision?

Answer (score 1):

The `#` matches zero or more further elements so subscriptions to `sport/#` will match `sport/`

This is easily tested with mosquitto_sub/mosquitto_pub

Publish:

```
$ mosquitto_pub -t "sport/" -m "foo"
```

Subscription:

```
$ mosquitto_sub  -v -t "sport/#"
sport/ foo
```

Comment: "zero or more further elements" is how I was basically thinking about it, but it also matches `sport`, which is sort of like less than zero compared to `sport/`, so I wish the spec would be clear about it

Comment: And if another library didn't match `sport/` it would be debatable which is buggy without the spec being completely clear about it

Comment: so I wonder if there's any clarification in some other official documentation rather than observed behavior?

Comment: Okay reading over other parts of the spec, I understand that `sport/` actually has two "topic levels" -- `sport` and the empty string, so in that case the `#` in `sport/#` is actually matching the empty string topic level, rather than zero topic levels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `sport/#` matches `sport/`.  The confusing aspect of the spec is that unlike file and directory names, **topic levels** can be empty strings.

The spec says:

> 4.7.1.1 Topic level separator
>
> The forward slash (‘/’ U+002F) is used to separate each level within a topic tree and provide a hierarchical structure to the Topic Names... **Adjacent Topic level separators indicate a zero length topic level**.

This means that `sport/` is parsed as not one, but *two* topic levels -- `sport` and the empty string -- hence the `#` in `sport/#` matches the second empty string topic level.  This is the same reason that `sport/+` matches `sport/` -- the `+` is matching the empty string level.